# converter parameter multi binding static resource

Tags: xaml

Here is my XAML code:

```
<TextBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="168,352,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280">
                <TextBox.Resources>
                    <sys:Double x:Key="fixedValue">2</sys:Double>
                </TextBox.Resources>
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DoubleConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="RM.SpecificGravity"/>
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource fixedValue}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
```

This is giving me this error:

> Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure you actually mention what your question is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to set the Path of the Binding. For binding directly to the Source object, you can set `Path="."`:

```
<Binding Path="." Source="{StaticResource fixedValue}"/>
```

---

That said, your MultiBinding might be replaced by a normal Binding, where the `fixedValue` is passed as ConverterParameter

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=RM.SpecificGravity,
                Converter={StaticResource DoubleConverter},
                ConverterParameter=2}" />
```

with a value-converter like this:

```
public class DoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var p = double.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```